# How can I make a POST request in a chrome extension that runs on twitter?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, post, google-chrome-extension, content-script

Currently, I am running a content script whenever https://twitter.com/home loads. The content script makes a POST request to my own API server (hosted on AWS) in the content script, using Axios. But I run into the following error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at '${endpoint url}' from origin 'https://twitter.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

I've only just started building chrome extensions so I'm probably doing it completely wrong. Please correct me and let me know how a feature like this could be implemented.

Comment: what is ${endpoint url} ? your API server on AWS ? it means you need to tweak your server's cross origin request policy to allow request from https://twitter.com to come thru

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 options:

1. Configure your AWS server to provide the CORS policy by adding an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header for example.
2. Do the request in your background script because CORS policy is not enforced there.

Further reading can be [found here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr).